# Laravel - deleting Many To Many Polymorphic Relations - Call to undefined method detach()

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables, `contents`, `taxonomies`, `taxonomicals`. Taxonomicals has fields:

```
taxonomy_id | taxonomical_id | taxonomical_type
```

The model for contents looks like this:

```
public function taxonomies()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Taxonomy', 'taxonomical');
}
```

The taxonomies model:

```
public function contents()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Content', 'taxonomical')->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
}
```

The taxonomical model:

```
public function content()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Content', 'taxonomical');
}
```

How can I delete only the relationship records in the taxonomicals table?
I would like to be able to delete all the records in the taxonomicals table for a given content:

I have tried with:

```
$content->taxonomies()->detach();
```

But, I got an error:

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach()

Comment: You have `$content->taxonomies()-->detach();;` where `--` and `;;` is there, Is it a typo?

Comment: That was a typo, I have that in my controller, when I am importing all contents, I first want to detach all of the old relations in the table.

Comment: Just to be sure - are you aware @NitishKumar pointed out **two** typos in your code?  You edited your question to fix one of them, but not the other, so it looks like you might have missed that.

Comment: oh, sorry, yes, that was just another typo here in the question, not in the code